# Python3 -- ValueError in Windows but not in Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, namedtuple

I had a python 3 script working great when running on Raspbian.  I moved it to my Windows machine and downloaded all the necessary packages but I get a ValueError now:

```
ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
```

The traceback shows the last line from my code that is called before the error is a `start()` to a multiprocessing process that reads a serial port.  The process only takes a multiprocessing Queue as an argument so the function can relay back what is on the serial line.  I'm thinking that's not the problem.  The only thing I can figure is that the output into the queue from the process is a namedtuple.  Is a namedtuple considered a ctype that can't be pickled?

But why would it work on Raspbian and not Windows?

Comment: the implementation of multiprocessing on Linux is *vastly* different from that on Windows, they're so different that I'd rather be surprised if code that was only tested in Raspbian, would work in Windows right away.

Comment: Try to reduce the code to a small program that reproduces the error (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)); otherwise, this question is too broad.